# Why is my Flow Collecting the Wrong Value?

Tags: kotlin, mobile-development, kotlin-stateflow

I thought I was pretty solid with flows in kotlin, but I ran into some strange behavior in the code below.

In my view model, I set my MutableStateFlow to a default (I've also tried `null`) value so that the UI has something while the rest of the uiState is gathered.

```
private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<MyUiState?> = MutableStateFlow(myUiStateDefault())
val uiState: StateFlow<MyUiState?> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

Upon initialization the uiState is meant to be updated with the new state. I've tried the assignment operator and the `copy` syntax.

```
.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
.collect {
   it?.let {
      _uiState.value = it // or _uiState.update { it.copy(...) }
   }
}
```

However, for some reason, the value that is collected turns out to be the default/old value instead of the new value from the `combine` block.

```
combine(...) { w, x, y, z ->
   ...
   MyUiState(...) // new value
}
```

In the fragment, I collect the state in this way.

```
val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value
```

I've tried calling the initialize function more than once and still the uiState does not get updated, and using Dispatchers.Main doesn't work.

Let me know if you have any questions. I suspect this could be a threading issue, but I'm not really sure either. I'm mostly confused at the fact my `collect` block is retrieving the `myUiStateDefault` value instead of the new `MyUiState` value created in the `combine` block.

Full code in my view model:

```
private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<MyUiState?> = MutableStateFlow(myUiStateDefault())
val uiState: StateFlow<MyUiState?> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

init {
   initUiState()
}

private fun initUiState() {
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      combine(...) { w, x, y, z ->
         ...
         MyUiState(...) // new value
      }
      .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
      .collect { // collects the default/old value here instead of the new value
         it?.let {
            _uiState.value = it // or _uiState.update { it.copy(...) }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you observe you collected the default value? This observation doesn't really seem possible, because we don't collect `uiState` here, but an entirely different flow which never emits this value. If you could, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @broot right. I'm logging some data in places where I can verify that the data I'm collecting does match up. I can't share said data, but, for example, the `myUiStateDefault` contains a value that is X, and I know the collected value from the combine should be Y because the logs say that is the value right before collection. When the value is collected, I get a MyUiState containing the value X instead of Y. So minor correction, the object collected is NOT the same reference as `myUiStateDefault` but it holds the same value. Does this help?

Comment: Why do you even `collect` in the viewmodel? The viewmodel should just transform the data flows from the underlying layers to a ui state that is consumed by your ui elements. The transformation is done by `combine`/`map`/etc., but never `collect`. This would look like something along the lines of the last example in @Jan Itor's answer.

Comment: Your use of Dispatchers.IO is unnecessary in both locations you used it, suggesting maybe there is a misunderstanding you have about how flows and flow operators work. Using `stateIn` as shown in Jan Igor’s answer would definitely clean up your code quite a bit but the issue you’re describing must be caused by code downstream from what you’ve shown here.

Comment: Or maybe you’re doing something funky with reuse of instances of some mutable class either inside your combine lambda or in your upstream flows.